# AddEventListener for loop closure

Tags: javascript

Before I get linked to anything, I want you to know that I have read plenty about my issue. And I know this question's title will probably be edited to duplicate, which am completely okay with if I end up getting a solution & explanation to my problem.

So I have a table and wanted to change the names of the headers, on the click of them. What I basically want is whenever I click on one of the headers. I want to take its innerHTML and make it a textbox's value.

I have been trying to do this with a for loop without success. Each time I click on any of the headers and my textbox is filled with the last header. I already have a working version of my code with individual click events functions for each, but I think it would be possible with a for loop & a closure.

```js
/*/ =========================================================== /*/

for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
  document.getElementById('H' + i).addEventListener("click", HeaderClicked);
  console.log("TH " + i + " click event added!");

  for (var x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
    function HeaderClicked() {
      headerText.focus();
      headerText.value = tableHeaders[x].innerHTML;
      console.log("TH clicked");
      console.log("X is " + x);
    }
  }
}


/*/ =========================================================== /*/

document.getElementById('Rename').addEventListener("click", Renaming);

var tableHeaders = [document.getElementById("H1"), document.getElementById("H2"),
  document.getElementById("H3")
];
var headerText = document.getElementById("headerText");

function Renaming() {
  var newName = document.getElementById("newName").value;
  var addRowLabel = document.getElementById("addRowLabel");

  switch (headerText.value) {
    case tableHeaders[0].innerHTML:
      tableHeaders[0].innerHTML = newName;
      addRowLabel.innerHTML = "Data(" + newName + " " + tableHeaders[1].innerHTML + " " + tableHeaders[2].innerHTML + ")";
      console.log("Header 1 changed!");
      break;
    case tableHeaders[1].innerHTML:
      tableHeaders[1].innerHTML = newName;
      addRowLabel.innerHTML = "Data(" + tableHeaders[0].innerHTML + " " + newName + " " + tableHeaders[2].innerHTML + ")";
      console.log("Header 2 changed!");
      break;
    case tableHeaders[2].innerHTML:
      tableHeaders[2].innerHTML = newName;
      console.log("Header 3 changed!");
      addRowLabel.innerHTML = "Data(" + tableHeaders[0].innerHTML + " " + tableHeaders[1].innerHTML + " " + newName + ")";
      break;
    default:
      console.log("Name doesn't exist");
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
  <script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.0/material.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>

<body>
  <table id="myTable" class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-shadow--2dp">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th id="H1" class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">ClickMe1</th>
        <th id="H2">ClickMe2</th>
        <th id="H3">ClickMe3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Acrylic (Transparent)</td>
        <td>25</td>
        <td>$2.90</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Plywood (Birch)</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>$1.25</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>$2.35</td>
      </tr>
  </table>

  <div id="Controls">
    <br>

    <div id="SmallerLabels" class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
      <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="headerText" autocomplete='off' />
      <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="CurrentName">Header name</label>
    </div>
    -
    <div id="SmallerLabels" class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
      <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="newName" autocomplete='off' />
      <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="NewName">Header New Name</label>
    </div>

    <button id="Rename" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--accent mdl-js-ripple-effect">
      Rename
    </button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
<style>
  button {
    margin: 10px 5px 5px 10px;
  }
  table {
    margin: 10px 5px 5px 10px;
  }
  #SmallerLabels {
    width: 140px;
  }
  #Controls {
    margin: auto 5px auto 10px;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Define `HeaderClicked` only once, somewhere global, and use `this` instead to refer to the `Hi` header element you'd like to switch the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
var headerText = document.getElementById("headerText");

for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
  (function(index){
    document.getElementById('H' + index).addEventListener("click",
      function(){
        headerText.focus();
        headerText.value = this.innerHTML;
      });
  })(i);
}
```

Basically, the idea is to create an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) to capture the scope of the loop variables within a closure.

Also note you don't need to have an array storing all header nodes, since you can get them from the click handler context with `this`.

Comment: Well, what is happening? What's the error? Are all the variables (e.g. `headerText`, `tableHeaders`) properly assigned?

Comment: Yes they are, it still always takes the last value (ClickMe3) which has a tableHeaders index number of 2 (tableHeaders[2])

Comment: Am sorry, but my index html is different than the one I posted so I got confused. Correction; it always takes the second value (ClickMe2) which has a tableHeaders index number of 1 (tableHeaders[1])

Comment: Oops, I made the mistake of blindly copying your code, which wasn't entirely correct. I've updated my answer with the corrections.

Comment: Works like a charm, I will definitely need to read more about closures to understand how they work. Thanks for your help!